# "Doctor Pérez did some surgery on my knee"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

What is the natural way to say in English that a certain doctor did some surgery on — for instance — my knee? In Spanish we say "El doctor Pérez me operó la rodilla". Is the following grammatical?

> Doctor Pérez did some surgery on my knee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with "performed surgery," but I think it's more likely one would say

> Doctor Pérez *operated* on my knee.

Comment: Ok, so almost the same expression as in Spanish. This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

What you provided is perfectly fine for conversational English.  If you wanted to polish it some, and make it more formal, you might say:

> Doctor Pérez *performed surgery* on my knee.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is "Doctor P. operated on my knee".